# Animation of the TextBlock property defined in the template of the element (Buttons)

Tags: c#, wpf

I apologize in advance for any mistakes, English is not my native.

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="LogOutButtonTheme">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                Background= "{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Width="{TemplateBinding Property=Width}"
                                Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}"
                                CornerRadius="10">
                            <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Property=Width}"
                                Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           FontSize="18"></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style.Setters>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                              To="85" Duration="0:0:0.2"  />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                              To="45" Duration="0:0:0.2"  />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Border.Grid.TextBlock.FontSize"
                              To="19" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"
                              To="80" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"
                              To="40" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Border.Grid.TextBlock.FontSize"
                              To="18" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
        
    </Style>
```

I have a WPF style for a button with various animations, but these ones don't work:

```xml
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Border.Grid.TextBlock.FontSize"
                              To="18" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />

<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Border.Grid.TextBlock.FontSize"
                              To="19" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />
```

My goal is to animate TextBlock's FontSize when the mouse enters or leaves the Button, but I don't know how to access a TextBlock's property which is defined like that:

```xml
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
      <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Width="{TemplateBinding Property=Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}" CornerRadius="10">
        <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Property=Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}">
          <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" />
        </Grid>
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Triggers must be inside a template. See the default element templates for an example.

https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.0/ms753328(v=vs.85)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="LogOutButtonTheme">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Background= "{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Property=Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}"
                            CornerRadius="10">
                            <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Property=Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PART_TBlock" Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="85" Duration="0:0:0.2"  />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="45" Duration="0:0:0.2"  />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_TBlock" To="19" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>

                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="80" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="40" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_TBlock" To="18" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger.Actions>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</FrameworkElement.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Кнопка" Style="{DynamicResource LogOutButtonTheme}"
            Width="100" Height="60"/>
</Grid>
```

Note that if the button is not explicitly dimensioned, your animation will throw an exception.

You can also bind the font size of the TextBlock to the font size of the button.
And then you can animate the font size of the button.

```
<FrameworkElement.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="LogOutButtonTheme">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Background= "{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Property=Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}"
                            CornerRadius="10">
                            <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Property=Width}"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Property=Height}">
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        </Style.Setters>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="85" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="45" Duration="0:0:0.2"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="19" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <EventTrigger.Actions>
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="80" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="40" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />
                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="FontSize" To="18" Duration="0:0:0.3"  />
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger.Actions>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>

    </Style>
</FrameworkElement.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Кнопка" Style="{DynamicResource LogOutButtonTheme}"
            Width="100" Height="60"/>
</Grid>
```